# `+` in dired-mode with icicles and ido enabled raises an error

Tags: dired, ido, icicles

I just installed icicles.

I use ido-mode for the minibuffer.

In a `dired` buffer, when I press `+` (bound to `dired-create-directory`), here is what happens:

- the first time, the error `icicle-restore-other-keymap-keys: Key sequence M-s M-s starts with non-prefix key M-s` comes up
- the second time and onward, the minibufferproperly comes up, but there's a twist. It says `Create directory: [current dir]` the first time as expected, then `Create directory: [current dir][current dir]` the next, etc. etc.

And after that, even other minibuffer interactions like define-variable would have `[current dir][current dir]...` in them.

My icicle configuration:

```
(use-package icicles
  :config (icy-mode 1))
```

My dired config:

```
(require 'dired-x)

(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook 'dired-hide-details-mode)

(setq global-auto-revert-non-file-buffers t)
(setq auto-revert-verbose nil)

(setq dired-dwim-target t)

(setq ls-lisp-use-insert-directory-program nil)
(require 'ls-lisp)

  (require 'dired)
  (defun dired-back-to-top ()
    (interactive)
    (beginning-of-buffer)
    (next-line 2))

  (define-key dired-mode-map
    (vector 'remap 'beginning-of-buffer) 'dired-back-to-top)

  (defun dired-jump-to-bottom ()
    (interactive)
    (end-of-buffer)
    (next-line -1))

  (define-key dired-mode-map
    (vector 'remap 'end-of-buffer) 'dired-jump-to-bottom)
```

I don't know enough about how icicles to know what's going on. I need some help.

Comment: OK, but what was the result? Did turning off `ido-mode` solve the problem?

Comment: It did. I had to actively tell emacs to turn off ido-mode but it did fix the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn off `ido-mode`.

Ido takes over the minibuffer, imposing its own, radically different key bindings and behavior.  Ido is not compatible with Icicles or with the vanilla Emacs minibuffer key bindings.

See [here](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Ido_and_IswitchB) for the relation between Ido and Icicles and how to get more Ido-like behavior using Icicles, if you like Ido behavior.